# Updating MySQL record with a decimal

Tags: php, mysql

I can not figure out how to update the record with a a decimal. For example. For room width, I need to add 4.2 but it rounds to 4. Please help

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == $form_number)) {
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE pano_table817 SET room_name=%s, room_width=%s, 
room_length=%s, delete_image=%s, is_pano=%s, outside_image=%s, 
floor_level=%s 
WHERE pano_id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['room_name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['room_width'],"numeric"),
                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['room_length'],"numeric"),
                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['delete_image'],"int"),
                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['is_pano'],"int"),
                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['outside_image'],"int"),
                    GetSQLValueString($_POST['floor_level'],"int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['pano_id'], "int")); 
mysql_select_db($database_ndctour, $ndctour);
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $ndctour) or die(mysql_error());
```

HTML Form:

```
<input type="text" name="room_width" class="input-text-integer" value="<?php 
echo $row_uploaded_images['room_width']?>">ft</td><td>
<input type="text" name="room_length" class="input-text-integer" value="<?
php echo $row_uploaded_images['room_length']?>">ft</td><td>
```

Comment: the output of `DESCRIBE PANO_TABLE817;` would be helpful... especially the data type of `room_width`

Comment: How old is this code? I believe `GetSQLValueString` is from macromedia DW, nothing from then should be in production today. `mysql_` should not be being used. Use PDO or mysqli. They support placeholders which will be similiar to your current usage.

Answer (score 2):

check your field definition for room_width, it needs to accept decimals with (in your case, with this specific example in mind) at least 1 decimal, and 2 total numbers. This would give you

```
DECIMAL(2,1)
```

give yourself a little room, and use something along the lines of

```
DECIMAL(4,2)
```

if you did have a valid mysql definition, let me know and ill look more in depth